# Update Card CVC on stripe

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments

How can we update a saved card on stripe for a customer using stripe API ?

- Stripe provides a way to update card details like card_exp_month, card_exp_year etc. But I cannot find how to update a CVC on existing card on stripe for a customer.

I tried TOKEN endpoint of stripe api : [Link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens) and PaymentMethod endpoint: [Link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods)  but i cannot find the result for updating Cvc for a card .

Answer (score 1):

Stripe doesn't store the CVC for cards. This is a value that the customer must pass during authorization and there's no way to update/access it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. You've already verified the user is the owner of the card, and the CVC is not stored; PCI standards forbid it. Subsequent charges with that payment method don't need or use the CVC from the first charge.

If you really want to force the user to pass a CVC check again, you can collect the full card information as a new payment method.